# Mapbox - Visualisation issue with passed data using jinja2

Tags: javascript, jinja2, mapbox

I'm trying to pass the coordinates for a polygon from my flask app to the html containing the mapbox gl using jinja2.

My flask app looks something like this:

```
@app.route('/<path:subpath>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def show_subpath(subpath):
if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        data = request.form
        name = 'Eine Karte'
        poly = coords
        return render_template('/map.html', name=name, polygon=poly)
    except:
        return 'That didnt work'
```

The script section containing the map in map.html looks like this:

```
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'TOKEN';
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
  center: [12.940985, 54.063782],
  zoom: 10
});

var geom = '{{ polygon }}';
map.on('load', function() {
  map.addControl(
    new MapboxGeocoder({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
        mapboxgl: mapboxgl
    })
  );
})

map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource('iso', {
      'type': 'geojson',
      'data': {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
          'type': 'Polygon',
          'coordinates': geom 
        }
      }
    });

    map.addLayer({
     'id': 'iso',
     'type': 'fill',
     // Use "iso" as the data source for this layer
     'source': 'iso',
     'layout': {},
     'paint': {
       // The fill color for the layer is set to a light purple
       'fill-color': '#088',
       'fill-opacity': 0.8
     }
   });
  });
  </script>
```

When I use "console.log(geom)" at the end of the script I can see, that the data is passed correctly. However the polygon isn't display on the map. When I hard code the coordinates they appear on the map. How can I visualize the passed data?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide a sample of the coordinates?

Comment: Something like this: `[
[
[-67.13734, 45.13745],
[-66.96466, 44.8097],
[-68.03252, 44.3252],
[-69.06, 43.98],
[-70.11617, 43.68405],
[-70.64573, 43.09008],
[-70.75102, 43.08003],
[-70.79761, 43.21973],
[-70.98176, 43.36789],
[-70.94416, 43.46633],
[-71.08482, 45.30524],
[-70.66002, 45.46022],
[-70.30495, 45.91479],
[-70.00014, 46.69317],
[-69.23708, 47.44777],
[-68.90478, 47.18479],
[-68.2343, 47.35462],
[-67.79035, 47.06624],
[-67.79141, 45.70258],
[-67.13734, 45.13745]
]
]` It's from the [mapbox tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple - you passed the polygon to mapbox as a `string`, while it requires a `GeoJSON` object. I replicated your code and got

> Error {message: "Input data given to 'maine' is not a valid GeoJSON object."}

What you want to do is **remove the quotes from your `geom` variable**. Just to be on the safe side, you can use [`tojson`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#tojson) so that it escapes certain characters so it doesn't cause unexpected errors, especially when you're using variables in `<script>` tags.

Modify `var geom = '{{ polygon }}';` into:

```
var geom = {{ polygon|tojson }};
```

and it should work!

You can also remove the additional variable if you're not doing any extra processing:

```js
map.addSource('maine', {
'type': 'geojson',
'data': {
'type': 'Feature',
'geometry': {
'type': 'Polygon',
// These coordinates outline Maine.
'coordinates':
    {{ polygon|tojson }}
}
}
});
```

Also, make sure that when you pass the arguments from flask, you're not adding quotes to make it into a string object.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I don't know why I didn't get it before, but that did the trick.